# How to implement a flutter layout more easily？

Tags: layout, flutter

I have a layout effect, I don't know how to implement it more easily? I have six or N child widgets, placed in a parent widget with two child widgets per row, each widget is 50% the width of the parent widget and height is the height /rows of the parent widget.

I can use column, row expanded to do this, but I don't think it's simple enough.If my child widgets are intermediate, I don't know how to create them dynamically.

The layout effect what I want to achieve:
[image]

The way I want to do it is the following pseudocode
I can do it in Android and iOS, but I don't know how to do it with flutter.

```
var parentWidget = Widget()

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var child = Widget()
    parentWidget.add(child)
}
```

The Flutter is implemented as follows. I can use column,row expanded to do this, but I don't think it's simple enough. If my child widgets are indeterminate, I don't know how to create them dynamically.

```
Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Row(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: Text("1"),),
              Expanded(child: Text("1"),),
            ],)
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child:Row(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: Text("1"),),
              Expanded(child: Text("1"),),
            ],),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Row(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(child: Text("1"),),
              Expanded(child: Text("1"),),
            ],),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: If you have many items, it's better to use ListView

Comment: @PhucTran yes，But I don't want the scrolling effect, I just want the child widgets to split the parent widget to fit different screen sizes, so there aren't too many children, maybe six, maybe eight

Comment: It's only scrollable if the number of items is big enough (some are out of screens)

Comment: Why not use a GridView? https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54079114/10269042

Comment: @ishaan I don't want the scrolling effect. If the height of the parent widget changes, the height of the child widget changes automatically

Comment: You can use GridView and you opt to turn off scroll using physics attributes...but not sure about changing height dynamically....maybe you could use Expanded Widget for each child. Otherwise layout will overflow. Also take a look at Flexible or Box constraints.

Comment: Another thing try to look for responsive layout usually you must use LayoutBuilder, BoxConstraint  and MediaQuery and there are attributes like aspectRatio

Comment: @stucked_overflow yes,I use LayoutBuilder to get the size of the parent widget, calculate the width and height of each child widget so that each child widget is the same size, and then put them in wrap to arrange themselves

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a way to deal with this requirement by calculating the width and height of each child widget and then placing them in wrap to arrange themselves

```
class RowFixedWrap extends StatefulWidget {
  final double spacing;
  final double runSpacing;
  final int columnCount;
  final List<Widget> childern;

  RowFixedWrap(
      {Key key, this.spacing, this.runSpacing, this.columnCount, this.childern})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _FixedWrapState();
  }
}

class _FixedWrapState extends State<RowFixedWrap> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        var itemWidth =
            (constraints.maxWidth - widget.spacing * (widget.columnCount - 1)) /
                widget.columnCount;
        var rows = widget.childern.length % widget.columnCount != 0
            ? (widget.childern.length ~/ widget.columnCount) + 1
            : (widget.childern.length ~/ widget.columnCount);
        var itemHeight =
            (constraints.maxHeight - widget.runSpacing * (rows - 1)) / rows;

        return Wrap(
            spacing: widget.spacing,
            runSpacing: widget.runSpacing,
            children: widget.childern.map((widget) {
              return SizedBox(
                width: itemWidth,
                height: itemHeight,
                child: widget,
              );
            }).toList());
      },
    );
  }
}
```

```
Expanded(
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: RowFixedWrap(
        spacing: 10,
        runSpacing: 10,
        columnCount: 2,
        childern: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
```